# How do I know if an object comes from the Solar System or not?

Tags: energy, solar-system, orbital-motion

I'm told that if the total energy of an object near the Sun is negative, then it comes from the Solar System; if positive, it is extrasolar.

I don't understand why. Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it is referring to [specific orbital energy](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy)
$$
\epsilon=\frac{v^2}{2}-\frac{\mu}{r}
$$
Where $v$, $\mu$ and $r$ are the velocity, gravitational parameter and distance to the sun.

In that case it would be the other way around. So if negative then it comes from the solar system, if positive it is extrasolar.

But our solar system does not only consist of the sun, other celestial bodies are also part of it. These bodies, especially the gas giants, can also have a big influence on the trajectory of other bodies when close enough (see [gravity slingshots](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist)). So this means that the specific orbital energy does not guarantee that something came from inside or outside the solar system. Good examples are the two [Voyager probes](http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov).

But you mention spaceships, which would suggest that there is some control over it and is not just surrendered to the external forces (mainly gravity).

**Edit**
The path of an object in a gravitational well is described by
$$
r(\theta)=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos{\theta}},
$$
where $\theta$ is the [true anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_anomaly), $a$ is the semi-major axis, which can be expressed as a function of $\epsilon$
$$
a=\frac{-\mu}{2\epsilon}
$$
and $e$ is the eccentricity, which can also be described as a function of $\epsilon$
$$
e=\sqrt{1+\frac{2\epsilon h^2}{\mu^2}}
$$
where $h$ is the specific angular momentum.

An object will be able to escape the solar system if its trajectory extend infinitely far away ($r=\infty$). And this will be the case when $1+e\cos{\theta}=0$. Since $\theta$ is a variable and the rest a constants, from this follows that $e\geq1$, so $e^2=1+\frac{2\epsilon h^2}{\mu^2}\geq1$.
And therefore $\frac{\epsilon h^2}{\mu^2}\geq0$, but because $h^2$ and $\mu^2$ are always positive this will only be true when $\epsilon\geq0$ (so when positive).

Comment: It might be, i don't really understand the specific orbital energy wikipedia page, i'm not really good in english. But yes, i assume the total energy of the object is just the sum of his kinetic and gravitational energies.

Comment: But then, how the energy can tell the path ?

Comment: I added some text to my answer which explains this.

Answer (score 2):

If the object is only influenced by the gravity of the sun, then it follows a [Kepler orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit). Such an object has two constants of motion:

1. The [specific orbital energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy), which is the sum of the object's kinetic and potential energy, divided by the object's mass:
   $$
   E = \frac{1}{2}v^2 - \frac{\mu}{r} = \frac{1}{2}v_r^2 + \frac{1}{2}v_t^2 - \frac{\mu}{r},
   $$
   where $v_r$ is the radial velocity component (the velocity component in the direction of the sun) and $v_t$ is the tangential velocity component (the velocity component perpendicular to the radial velocity).
2. The [specific relative angular momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_relative_angular_momentum)
   $$
   \vec{h} = \vec{r}\times\vec{v},
   $$
   so that
   $$
   h = ||\vec{h}|| = rv_t.
   $$

Combining these, we get
$$
E = \frac{1}{2}v_r^2 + \frac{h^2}{2r^2} - \frac{\mu}{r}.
$$
Suppose that the object comes from outside the solar system. If we set $r=\infty$, we get
$$
E = \frac{1}{2}v_r(\infty)^2 \geqslant 0.
$$
Conversely, the object is bound to the solar system if and only if $E < 0$. In that case, there are two radii at which $v_r^2=0$: indeed, we then get
$$
E = \frac{h^2}{2r^2} - \frac{\mu}{r},
$$
which is a quadratic equation in $r$, with two solutions: a minimum distance and a maximum distance, called the [apsides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsis).